# Alternative for ranking of a response

Tags: ranking

Is there a regression approach for predicting the rankings (ordering) as an endogenous variable?

I would like to fit a regression to a dataset where the response is the order of a variable: 1st, 2nd, 3rd. Mainly, Mainly, I would like to know the influence of the 5 $X$s variables on this ranking.

My approach so far has been calculating the uniform-associated variable:

$U_i = \frac{R_i}{n+1}$

where $R_i$ is the ranking of the i-th individual.

Any further ideas or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/41540/1/dls_sac2017.pdf see related work section